# My makefile keeps compiling over itself; what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I'm not sure if there is some built-in variable or rule that I don't know about, or if something is wrong with make, or if I'm just crazy.

For one of my projects, I have a makefile as follows:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-O3 `libpng-config --cflags`
LFLAGS=-lm `libpng-config --ldflags`

OBJS=basic_render.o render.o mandel.o
BINS=basic_render

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(BINS)

clean:
    rm -f $(BINS) $(OBJS)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

%: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS)
```

When building, I want to simply be able to run

```
make clean
make
```

to build everything in the BINS list.

This works all right at first, but for some reason, the behaviour changes after I edit a source file.

Before editing source file:

```
$ make clean
rm -f basic_render basic_render.o render.o mandel.o
$ make
g++ -O3 `libpng-config --cflags` -c -o basic_render.o basic_render.cpp
g++ -O3 `libpng-config --cflags` -c -o render.o render.cpp
g++ -O3 `libpng-config --cflags` -c -o mandel.o mandel.cpp
g++ -lm `libpng-config --ldflags` -o basic_render basic_render.o render.o mandel.o
rm mandel.o basic_render.o render.o
```

I can do this over and over again and it works just fine. After I make changes to `basic_render.cpp` (literally just changing a couple of constants), it suddenly changes to this:

```
$ make clean
g++ -O3 `libpng-config --cflags` -c -o basic_render.o basic_render.cpp
g++ -O3 `libpng-config --cflags` -c -o render.o render.cpp
g++ -O3 `libpng-config --cflags` -c -o mandel.o mandel.cpp
g++ -lm `libpng-config --ldflags` -o makefile basic_render.o render.o mandel.o
rm mandel.o basic_render.o render.o
makefile:1: warning: NUL character seen; rest of line ignored
makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

not only did `make clean` just try to compile the program, it compiled `basic_render` with the output set in `Makefile`, overwriting the `Makefile` itself.

After editing `basic_render.cpp`, I looked in `Makefile`, and it hadn't changed, so it's not like my editor is changing the makefile or something.

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an MCVE of your problem:

```
$ ls -R
.:
bar.c  main.c  Makefile

$ cat main.c
extern int bar(void);

int main(void)
{
    bar();
    return 0;
}

$ cat bar.c
int bar(void)
{
    return 42;
}

$ cat Makefile
OBJS := main.o bar.o
BINS := prog

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(BINS)

%: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS) $(BINS)
```

Make first time:

```
$ make
cc    -c -o main.o main.c
cc    -c -o bar.o bar.c
cc -o prog main.o bar.o
rm bar.o main.o
```

Pause to notice the undesired consequence of [10.4 Chains of Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html):

```
rm bar.o main.o
```

All of the object files are auto-deleted after the program is linked, defeating the purpose
of Make. The implicit rules to blame for that are our own implicit rule:

```
%: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS)
```

plus the built-in implicit rule<sup>1</sup>:

```
%.o: %.c
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

which together make an implicit rule chain that results in all of the object files
becoming [intermediate files](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html).

Moving on, let's update a source file:

```
$ touch main.c
```

and make a second time:

```
$ make
cc    -c -o main.o main.c
cc    -c -o bar.o bar.c
cc -o Makefile main.o bar.o
rm bar.o main.o
Makefile:1: warning: NUL character seen; rest of line ignored
Makefile:1: *** missing separator. Stop.
```

There is our Makefile clobbered by the linkage:

```
cc -o Makefile main.o bar.o
```

This snafu is explained in the manual [3.5 How Makefiles Are Remade](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html):

> Sometimes makefiles can be remade from other files, such as RCS or SCCS files.
>   If a makefile can be remade from other files, you probably want make to get an
>   up-to-date version of the makefile to read in.
>
> **To this end, after reading in all makefiles, make will consider each as a goal
>   target and attempt to update it. If a makefile has a rule which says how to update it
>   (found either in that very makefile or in another one) or if an implicit rule applies to it
>   (see Using Implicit Rules), it will be updated if necessary**.
>   After all makefiles have been checked, if any have actually been changed,
>   make starts with a clean slate and reads all the makefiles over again.
>   (It will also attempt to update each of them over again, but normally this will
>   not change them again, since they are already up to date.)

(Emphasis mine). Is there an implicit rule that is applicable to `Makefile` considered
as a target? Yes, it is:

```
%: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS)
```

since the target pattern `%` matches any file whatever. If we restore our clobbered
Makefile and try the same experiment thing again, this time with debugging:

```
make -d >debug.log 2>&1
```

the output will show us:

```
...
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile 'Makefile'...
Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file 'Makefile'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for 'Makefile'.
  ...
  ...
  Found an implicit rule for 'Makefile'.
  ...
  ...
  Finished prerequisites of target file 'Makefile'.
  Prerequisite 'main.o' is newer than target 'Makefile'.
  Prerequisite 'bar.o' is newer than target 'Makefile'.
 Must remake target 'Makefile'.
cc -o Makefile main.o bar.o
...
```

We can avoid this upshot, and also the self-defeating auto-deletion of
our object files, by not using a match-anything implicit rule to perform our
linkage. The customary thing is to make a program from its object files by
an explicit rule, e.g.

**Makefile (2)**

```
OBJS := main.o bar.o
BIN := prog

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS) $(BIN)
```

It appears that you cherish the option to have `BINS` be a list of multiple
programs:

> I want to simply be able to run
>
> make clean
>
> make
>
> to build everything in the BINS list.

But consider that with:

```
BINS := prog1 prog2
```

and the recipe:

```
%: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS)
```

as your way of making everything in the `BINS` list, you will just make the same program
twice, with two different names. And even if you *wanted* to do this, the way to do
it would be:

**Makefile (3)**

```
OBJS := main.o bar.o
BINS := prog1 prog2

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(BINS)

$(BINS): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS) $(BIN)
```

which runs like:

```
$ make
cc    -c -o main.o main.c
cc    -c -o bar.o bar.c
cc -o prog1 main.o bar.o
cc -o prog2 main.o bar.o
```

---

[1] You can get GNU Make to show you all its builtin-rules, and all the rest
of its rules for a particular build, with `make --print-data-base ...`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that the `%` target is somehow matching the `makefile` file and therefore using it as the target<sup>(1)</sup>.

My advice would be to change that line to:

```
$(BINS): $(OBJS)
```

and that should hopefully prevent `make` from thinking it should create a new `makefile` when the objects change.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Apart from the explicit rules you provide, `make` also has quite a lot of *implicit* rules.

If even *one* of those rules decides that it depends on `makefile` (this is often configured since a change to the `makefile` usually means that a full rebuild should be done, as the rules may well have changed), then the `%` target may then be used for the `makefile`.

And, since the objects have changed, the `makefile` that depends on them will be rebuilt.

I personally have *never* seen a `%` target since I believe that means the rule may match *any* target, including source files which you probably *don't* want overwritten.

If you're interested in seeing all those implicit rules, `make -d` should give you quite a bit of information such as the rules used and conditions checked for whether files need to be rebuilt - just be prepared to wade through a lot of output.

Comment: Yes, but it should only match given targets, which in this case would be $(BINS) and $(OBJS) from all. Also, would your solution work if $(BINS) contained more than one entry?

Comment: @supereater14, if *any* rule (explicit or implicit) decides that it depends on `makefile`, it will then use `%` target to "compile" to the `makefile` target. That's what I was trying to get at in my parentheses (I'll clarify), and probably what's happening in your case. I think, from memory, `make -d` will give you lots of information about what rules are being used though be prepared for a lot of output. And, yes, you can have multiple targets, it will simply treat it as multiple identical rules for each target.

Comment: All right, but do you see any way that something in here might depend on makefile? The makefile I gave is complete.

Comment: @supereater14, see the update. My guess is that there's an implicit rule for rebuilding everything when the `makefile` changes. But even if I'm wrong, the `make -d` suggestion should allow you to track down why it's happening.